# PIDL(or similar) on RHEL 7

Tags: rhel, samba, rhel7

I have a .idl (Interface Definition Language) file on my windows machine. I would like to get the same file to compile on my RHEL7 machine. I have looked everywhere to see if there was a compiler similar to MIDL that is available for RHEL. I came across a compiler called PIDL with Samba, however, when I installed Samba, PIDL was not a part of the installation. Does anybody know how to get PIDL on RHEL 7 and how to use it? OR if there is any other resource I can use to compile .idl files on RHEL7?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it here: [samba pidl](https://github.com/samba-team/samba/tree/master/pidl) if anybody else is interested.